# How does Twisted get response in client?

Tags: python, response, twisted, webclient

I'm reading  Twisted Network Programming Essentials. In Chapter 5, there is this code:

```
# encoding: utf-8
import sys

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.web.client import Agent

class ResourcePrinter(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, finished):
        self.finished = finished

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        '''
        data seems comes from response not transport
        '''
        print data

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.finished.callback(None) # Fire with None, no callback in deferred: finished


def printResource(response):
    finished = Deferred()
    print "idf: ", id(finished)
    # Dispatch IProtocol to handle response
    response.deliverBody(ResourcePrinter(finished))
    return finished

def printError(failure):
    print >> sys.stderr, failure

def stop(result):
    print type(result) # Result is None, not return value from printResource, why?
    reactor.stop()


if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print >> sys.stderr, "Usage: python e5-3.py URL"
    exit(1)

agent = Agent(reactor)
d = agent.request("GET", sys.argv[1])
d.addCallbacks(printResource, printError)
d.addBoth(stop)

reactor.run()
```

1. Why there are two deferred? → `d` and `finished`, how are they combined?
2. The return value of `printResource` is `finished`, why not pass to callback stop? (The arg result is `None`.)
3. What is the flow of the response, where does it begin and end? The flow seems to be that, `d` gets the response in chunks and passes it to callback `printResource`. In `printResource`, it dispatches to `IProtocol` to handle it. How does it work? Usually, `IProtocol` receives data from `ITransport`, but here it seems not.